# Como usar os valores de uma variavel PHP em um script externo javascript

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Estou querendo usar vuejs em um sistema próprio feito em php com MVC,

Quero pegar um array acessível na pagina e passar para o javascrip no momento do load, para que ele manipule a exibição. Sei que da para fazer isso com AJAX, mas acho que não se encaixa muito bem com a estrura do projeto, queria uma alternativa viavel sem ter que colocar em um input hidden ou coisa do tipo

Answer (score 1):

Coloque ele em uma variável javascript que pode ser acessada no seu código:

```
<script>
    var array = [ <?php echo implode(",", $array); ?> ]
</script>
```